# Keep rows from a dataframe whose index name is NOT in a given list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have a list with tuples, and a multi-index dataframe. I want to find the rows of the dataframe whose indices are NOT included in the list of tuples, and create a new dataframe with these elements. Any help? Thanx!

Comment: Any attempts? At least a intuitive solution would be iterate over rows and nest another iteration over the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.isin.html) with a negation to explicitly filter your DataFrame:

```
new_df = df[~df.index.isin(list_of_tuples)]
```

Alternatively, use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to remove the tuples you don't want to be included in the new DataFrame.

```
new_df = df.drop(list_of_tuples)
```

From a couple simple tests, using `isin` appears to be faster, although `drop` is a bit more readable.